# Отображение сайта и разрешение экрана.

Tags: html

Ребят, помогите с глупым вопросом, сайт при разрешении выше 1400×1050 начинает уезжать влево, при меньшем отображается по центру.

Comment: margin: auto;

Comment: стоит это и всё равно)

Comment: ну код или ссылку на сайт, наши экстрасенсы в отпуске до сих пор :)

Comment: а флоат стоит?

Comment: http://distira.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Оберни содержимое `body` в `<div style="width: 1160px; float: none; margin: 0 auto;"></div>`
2. Убери стиль body `{width: 1160px;}` (это 64 строка в html)

p.s. Убери стили из html.